# Vuejs: Displaying Selected Item On a Page You are On

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I need some help displaying a selected an item on the page you are on. I have three component Home, Product, and Index. The Index component is Global component which have a list of items with a route-link attached to them to got to the Product Page (Component) and display the item that was click. I am passing the item in the route-link as params to be able to access the item on the Product page. I am using the Index Component on the Home component to display all item. And when I click an item from the Index component from the Home page, it go to the Product page and display that item. That part is working fine, but when I am on the Product page and I click an item from the Index component, it is not displaying the clicked item in the Product page. I really need some help how to solve this problem.

Main.js code

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App'
import router from './router/routes'
import Index from './components/Index'

Vue.component('list-items', Index)

Vue.config.productionTip = false

/* eslint-disable no-new */
new Vue({
el: '#app',
router,
components: {App},
template: '<App/>'
})
```

Route.js File

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import Home from '../pages/Home'
import Product from '../pages/Product'

Vue.use(Router)

export default new Router({
  routes: [
 {
  path: '' || '/',
  name: 'Home',
  component: Home
},
{
  path: '/product',
  name: 'Product',
  component: Product,
  props: true
   }
 ],
mode: 'history'
})
```

Home.vue component

```
<template>
<div class="container-fluid p-0">
<list-items />
</div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
name: 'Home',
data: () => ({

  })
}
```

Product.vue component

```
<template>
<div class="container-fluid p-0">
  <div class="container-fluid py-5">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-7">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <img v-bind:src="item.url" alt="" class="img-fluid">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 margin-padding-right">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <h3>{{$route.params.product.name}}</h3>
          <h5 class="price">${{item.price}}</h5>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <br>
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="col-md-12 related-item">
        <h5>Related Items</h5>
      </div>

      <list-items />

    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

```
<script>

export default {
   name: 'Product',

   props: ['product'],

  data: () => ({
    quantity: 1,
    item: {
      name: '',
      url: ''
    }
}),
mounted () {
  if (this.product) {
  this.item.name = this.product.name
  this.item.url = this.product.image
  }
},
watch: {
    change: function (newValue, oldValue) {
     this.item.name = newValue.product.name
      }
   }
 }
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>

</style>
```

This is an image of what I am trying to achieve.
[image]

Comment: Why not using `vuex`?

Comment: I just start using Vue, and I just now hear of Vuex. I will take a look at it.

Comment: Passing from parent component to child components and callback functions to change them is hard, `vuex` is a state management make it easy for us.

Comment: You don't need vuex for this, just use the router effectively.  Can you show your routes and the router-link you're using in list-items.  [Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/reverent-ganguly-vddvt?file=/src/components/ListItems.vue) is a quick CodeSandbox i put together showing how to accomplish it.

Comment: Sorry I total forget to add my route js file. I have add my added it now